# PHP - foreach how to store the array to mysql

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to store array into mysql db something like this

```
item_row  = nike,adidas,puma
qty_row   = 1,3,2
total_row = 100,200,150
```

foreach

```
  foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $values) {
      $item_name = $values['item-name'];
      $item_qty = $values['item-qty'];
      $item_price = $values['item-price'];
  }
```

Let me know how to do that?

**update**

```
  foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $values) {
      $item_name[] = $values['item-name'];
      $item_qty[] = $values['item-qty'];
      $item_price[] = $values['item-price'];
  }

  $item_row = implode(",", $item_name);
  $qty_row = implode(",", $item_qty);
  $total_row = implode(",", $item_price);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're doing here is circumventing the use of linking relational tables.  So if down the line, you need scalability and speed, consider creating a few linking tables between the order and the quantities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
item_row = implode(',', $_SESSION['order']['item-name']);
qty_row = implode(',', $_SESSION['order']['item-qty']);
total_row = implode(',', $_SESSION['order']['item-price']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a class to manage the connection to the data base and the query execution let me add it to you:

```
class DbConnection
{
var $ReturnQuery;
function Connect()
{
    $connection = mysql_connect("serverName", "user", "password");
    $DbSelect = mysql_select_db("databaseName", $connection);
    if ($DbSelect)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
function Execute($Query)
{
    $ExecuteQuery = mysql_query($Query);
    $affected = mysql_affected_rows();
    if ($affected != -1)
    {
        if ($affected != 0)
        {
            if ($ExecuteQuery != 1)
            {
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($ExecuteQuery))
                {
                    $ResulArray[] = $row;
                }
                $this->ReturnQuery = $ResulArray;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->ReturnQuery = '';
            return 0;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->ReturnQuery = '';
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

and then you can create instances to execute your query:

```
require_once('Includes/DbConnection.php');
    $this->db = new DbConnection();
    $this->db->Connect();

$query = "insert into items (item_name, item_qty, item_price) values ('".$item_name."', '".$item_qty."', '"$item_price"');

$query_safe = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$this->db->Execute($query_safe);
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: Hi Alejandra. Your code looks neat. However, security best practice for SQL use in PHP is to use PDO and prepared statements. Have a look at this page: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Top_5#P3:_SQL_Injection

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $values) {

 mysql_query('INSERT INTO tablename (name, qty, price) VALUES("'.$values['item-name'].'", "'.$values['item-qty'].'", "'.$values['item-price'].'"');
}
```

Comment: This post is an answer to the question "How do I open myself to SQL injections?"

Comment: To be fair, the session is server-side and its contents could have already been sanitized :P Though prepared statements are always best.

Comment: @Lucas... you ALWAYS sanitize you data, nothing is ever safe, including data from the database itself.  By assuming some piece of data is safe because it didn't come directly from user input is a sure way to get SQL injected from a more complex method.